# How to retrieve LDAP data in Grails?

Tags: grails, ldap

I am trying to use the Grails plugin 'directory services' to access LDAP data. I am unable to configure it in GGTS. Can anyone help me with the code or directions to be used in coding a program for LDAP access in GGTS.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the documentation http://lr.github.io/directory-service/guide/configuration.html to see how to configure the plugin ?
This is a client and this means you have to install / configure also a ldap server. Have a look at the apache directory project https://directory.apache.org to get a ldap client / server . Afterwards you can connect from Grails as client to the Ldap-Server.

Comment: Thanks...!! I had tried configuration thing. But I am unable to use it. Tried everything as the documentation but getting a lot many errors. Even few methods not working too. I am getting all runtime errors.